# Javascript regular express repeating pattern matching excluding wod

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string

```
var str = '"/**' +
'\n* @doc {' +
'\n*   description: "Invalid login without user", ' +
'\n*   request: "/v2/login", ' +
'\n*   response: "login-invalid-user.json"' +
'\n* }' +
'\n*/' +
'\n some code goes here' +
'\n some code goes here' +
'\n some code goes here' +
'\n/**' +
'\n* @doc {' +
'\n*   description: "Invalid login without user", ' +
'\n*   request: "/v2/login", ' +
'\n*   response: "login-invalid-user.json"' +
'\n* }' +
'\n*/"';
```

and I wanted to find strings between with `@doc {` and `}`, so that results comes with length `2`

I can get this with regex, 
`var matches = str.match(/\@doc \{[^\}]+\}/gm);`

However, I also want to have some JSON objects as values. In that case the above regex does not work.

```
var str = '"/**' +
'\n* @doc {' +
'\n*   description: "Invalid login without user", ' +
'\n*   request: {url: "/v2/login1"}, ' + // <--- THIS IS CHANGED
'\n*   response: "login-invalid-user.json"' +
'\n* }' +
'\n*/' +
'\n some code goes here' +
'\n some code goes here' +
'\n some code goes here' +
'\n/**' +
'\n* @doc {' +
'\n*   description: "Invalid login without user", ' +
'\n*   request:  {url: "/v2/login2"}, ' + // <--- THIS IS CHANGED
'\n*   response: "login-invalid-user.json"' +
'\n* }' +
'\n*/"'
```

Thus, I tried the following to exclude `@doc` within matches.

```
str.match(/\@doc \{(?!@doc)+}/gm)
str.match(/\@doc \{(?!@doc)*}/gm)
str.match(/\@doc \{[\s\S]+(?!\@doc)\}/gm)
str.match(/\@doc \{(?!@doc)[\s\S]+}/gm)
str.match(/\@doc \{(?!\@doc)+\}/gm)
```

I think I am doing wrongly to exclude word `@doc` with those regex.

What's the best regex to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there . Just put the negated character class inside  a capturing group and then push the contents of first capturing group into an array.

```
/\@doc \{([^\}]+)\}/g
```

**Example:**

```
> var str = '"/**' +
... '\n* @doc {' +
... '\n*   description: "Invalid login without user", ' +
... '\n*   request: "/v2/login", ' +
... '\n*   response: "login-invalid-user.json"' +
... '\n* }' +
... '\n*/' +
... '\n some code goes here' +
... '\n some code goes here' +
... '\n some code goes here' +
... '\n/**' +
... '\n* @doc {' +
... '\n*   description: "Invalid login without user", ' +
... '\n*   request: "/v2/login", ' +
... '\n*   response: "login-invalid-user.json"' +
... '\n* }' +
... '\n*/"';
undefined
> var re = /\@doc \{([^\}]+)\}/g;
undefined
> var m;
undefined
> while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
... console.log(m[1]);
... }

*   description: "Invalid login without user", 
*   request: "/v2/login", 
*   response: "login-invalid-user.json"
* 

*   description: "Invalid login without user", 
*   request: "/v2/login", 
*   response: "login-invalid-user.json"
```

Blank line exists in-between two is mainly because the above regex would capture also the \n character exists just after to `{` bracket.

**Update:**

```
> var str = '"/**' +
... '\n* @doc {' +
... '\n*   description: "Invalid login without user", ' +
... '\n*   request: {url: "/v2/login1"}, ' + // <--- THIS IS CHANGED
... '\n*   response: "login-invalid-user.json"' +
... '\n* }' +
... '\n*/' +
... '\n some code goes here' +
... '\n some code goes here' +
... '\n some code goes here' +
... '\n/**' +
... '\n* @doc {' +
... '\n*   description: "Invalid login without user", ' +
... '\n*   request:  {url: "/v2/login2"}, ' + // <--- THIS IS CHANGED
... '\n*   response: "login-invalid-user.json"' +
... '\n* }' +
... '\n*/"';
undefined
> var m;
undefined
> var re = /\@doc \{([\S\s]*?)\}(?=\n)/g;
undefined
> var m;
undefined
> while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
... console.log(m[1]);
... }

*   description: "Invalid login without user", 
*   request: {url: "/v2/login1"}, 
*   response: "login-invalid-user.json"
* 

*   description: "Invalid login without user", 
*   request:  {url: "/v2/login2"}, 
*   response: "login-invalid-user.json"
* 
undefined
```

Comment: Thanks, and +1,  I have run your regex, and it's better, but not exactly what I wanted. I have added another example I wanted to parse. If you don't mind please run your regex with the example that I added, and sorry for not providing this at the beginning.

Comment: @allenhwkim: Note that this solution works with the assumption that the closing bracket of `@doc{}` ends with new line, and no closing `}` in `request` is followed by new line. Otherwise, stuffs like this happen https://regex101.com/r/nT6yH3/2

Comment: @AvinashRaj, thanks. I think it should be more programming that just regex. To save my time, I changed to use `{{` and `}}` instead.